# how to add values from my object to Highchart using Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, highcharts

i already get the values from my objects and i want to display it in my Highchart when Graph button is click but i dont know how to show it in my chart here is my code

In HTML

```
<button id="myBtn" class="btn">Add Entry</button>
<div id="myForm"></div><br/>
<button id="btnGraph" class="btn">Graph</button>
<div id="myGraph"></div>
<div id="new"></div>
```

In jquery

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#btnGraph').prop('disabled', true);

    $("#myBtn").click(function()
    {
        $('#btnGraph').prop('disabled', true);
        addCountry();
    });

    $(document).on("keyup blur", "input[type^='text']", function()
    {
        var empty = false;

        $("input[type^='text']").filter(function()
        {
             if($(this).val().trim()=='')
                 empty = true;      
        });

        $('#btnGraph').prop('disabled', empty);
    });

    $("#btnGraph").click(function()
    {
         graphPopulation();
    });
});

function graphPopulation()
{
    var arrayForSeries = [];
    var counter = $("[id^=country]").length;

    for (var i = 1; i <= counter; i++) 
    {
        var series = {};
        var n = $('#country-' + i).val();
        var d = parseInt($('#population-' + i).val());

        series.name = n;
        series.data = [d];
        arrayForSeries.push(series);
    }

    $("#new").html("<br/>"+JSON.stringify(arrayForSeries));
    //The value of "#new" depends on the user I just show it to have an idea what are the values that i get, input example
    //[{"name":"Canada","data":[49]},{"name":"Denmark","data":[83]},{"name":"Malta","data":[48]},{"name":"South Africa","data":[42]}]

    $('#myGraph').highcharts(
    {
        chart: {type: 'column'},
        title: {text: 'Population 2014'},
        subtitle: {text: 'Population Chart'},
        xAxis: {categories: ['Population(2014)']},
        yAxis: {min: 0, title: {text: 'Population'}},
        tooltip: {valueSuffix: ' people'},
        plotOptions: {column: {pointPadding: 0.2, borderWidth: 0}},

        //I need to put it in my chart so the format should be
        //series: [{"name":"Canada","data":[49]},{"name":"Denmark","data":[83]},{"name":"Malta","data":[48]},{"name":"South Africa","data":[42]}]

        series: JSON.stringify(arrayForSeries))
    });
}
```

I hope you can help me, my problem is only inserting the user data in the highchart..

Comment: Can you provide a simple fiddle?

Comment: sure here it is http://jsfiddle.net/s8p2rg2c/1/ i made some editing  by the way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply get rid of the `JSON.stringify` in   `var result = JSON.stringify(arrayForSeries);` you want to pass an array and not a string. Removing the stringify should solve your problem.
See http://jsfiddle.net/s8p2rg2c/2/

Comment: wow just wow.. i cant believe that it is just simple and i need not to be stringify hahaha thank you very much you helped me a lot i feel so stupid.. so the series dont accept string just array right? thank you again:)